# Heir extension of an invariant type.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I was asked to prove that given a definable set $G$ in a model $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}\preccurlyeq \mathcal{N}$. If a type $p\in S_G(M)$ is $G(M)$-invariant, then any of its heir extension to $\mathcal{N}$ is $G(N)$-invariant.

I tried assuming the extension $q$ of $p$ is not $G(N)$-invariant. Then, there are $b,b'\in N$ with $tp(b/G(N))=tp(b'/G(N))$ and $\varphi(x,y)$ a $L(M)$-formula such that $\varphi(x,b)\wedge \neg \varphi(x,b')\in q$. As $q$ is a heir to $p$, there are tuples $m,m'\in M$ such that $\varphi(x,m)\wedge \neg\varphi(x,m')\in p$. Here I don't know how to continue. I would like to have $tp(m/G(M))=tp(m'/G(M))$ but I don't see how to deduce it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct definition of $G(M)$-invariant? Usually, we think about global types (types over the monster model $\mathcal{U}$) which are invariant over a small set $A$. In this context, $p$ is fixed by every automorphism in $\text{Aut}(\mathcal{U}/A)$ if and only if for every formula $\varphi(x;y)$ and any $b,b'$ with $\text{tp}(b/A) = \text{tp}(b'/A)$, we have $\varphi(x;b)\in p$ iff $\varphi(x;b')\in p$. If we replace $\mathcal{U}$ by an arbitrary model $M$, or if we replace $A$ by a definable set (which is not small in $\mathcal{U}$), the equivalence no longer holds.

Comment: ... So I might expect a $G(M)$-invariant type in $S(M)$ to mean a type $p$ such that for every formula $\varphi(x;y)$ and any $b,b'$ with $\text{tp}(b/G(M)) = \text{tp}(b'/G(M))$, we have $\varphi(x;b)\in p$ iff $\varphi(x;b')\in p$

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right, I was thinking in the monster model, I will correct it

Comment: @AlexKruckman Looking at it again it seems that compactness might solve it. Because for all $\psi\in tp(b/G(M))$ the formula $\psi(x,b)\wedge\neg \phi(x,b')\wedge ( \psi(b)\iff \psi(b'))$ belongs to $q$. Hence, for all $\psi\in tp(b/G(M))$, there are $m,m'\in M$ such that $\psi(x,m)\wedge\neg \phi(x,m')\wedge ( \psi(m)\iff \psi(m'))$ belongs to $p$. Now compactness theorem will give us $m,m'$ with the same type over $G(M)$ witnessing that $p$ is not $G(M)$-invariant right?

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández unfortunately that argument does not quite work, since the elements $m,m'$ that you obtain from compactness will not necessarily lie in $M$. (indeed, there's nothing to stop them from just being the original $b$ and $b'$.)

Comment: is there meant to be some kind of saturation hypothesis on $M$?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom You are right, I have no saturation hypothesis on $M$.

Comment: (@AdrianPortilloFernández oh, and another problem with your argument is that you are implicitly assuming that $p$ is a definable type, as otherwise there is in general no first-order way to express the assertion $\varphi(x,b)\in p$. was it assumed that $p$ is a definable type?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not true as written. For instance, let $M=(\mathbb{Q},<)$, and let $N$ be any elementary extension of $M$ containing elements $a,c$ such that $0<a<c<q$ for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $q>0$. Now, define the formula $G(x)\equiv x\leqslant 0$ and let $p(x)\in S_1(M)$ be the unique type containing the formulas $$\{x>q:q\in\mathbb{Q},q\leqslant 0\}\cup\{x<q:q\in\mathbb{Q},q>0\}.$$ Now, $p(x)$ is $G(M)$-invariant. Indeed, suppose two elements $q_1,q_2\in\mathbb{Q}$ have the same type over $G(M)$. If $q_1\neq q_2$, then we must have $q_1,q_2>0$, and so we have $0<q_1\in p$ and $0<q_2\in p$. By quantifier elimination for $\text{DLO}$, every formula is equivalent to a Boolean combination of formulas of the form $x=y$ and $x<y$, so this suffices to show that $p(x)$ is $G(M)$-invariant. (As an aside, note too that, again by quantifier elimination, $p$ is a definable type, since $x<q$ lies in $p$ for an element $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $q>0$.)

However, consider the unique type $q(x)\in S_1(N)$ containing the formulas $$\{x>n:n\in N,n\leqslant a\}\cup\{x<n:n\in N,n>a\}.$$ Certainly $q(x)\supseteq p(x)$, and it is also an heir of $p$, again by quantifier elimination for $\text{DLO}$. But $q(x)$ is not $G(N)$-invariant, since it contains $x>a$ and $x<c$ even though $\operatorname{tp}(a/G(N))=\operatorname{tp}(c/G(N))$. So this gives the desired counterexample.

---

The desired result *does* hold if $M$ is $\aleph_0$-saturated and if $p$ is a definable type. To see this, suppose $q\supseteq p$ is an heir of $p$ in $S(N)$ that is not $G(N)$-invariant. Then there is a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ and elements $n,n'\in N$ such that $\varphi(x,n)\wedge\neg\varphi(x,n')\in q$ but $\operatorname{tp}(n/G(N))=\operatorname{tp}(n'/G(N))$. Now, if $p$ is definable, then there is a formula $d_p x\varphi(x,y)$ such that $$\varphi(x,m)\in p\iff M\models d_px\varphi(x,m),$$ for any $m\in M$. Now, for any formula $\psi(y,z_1,\dots,z_n)$ without parameters, define a corresponding formula $$\widehat{\psi}(y,y')\equiv\forall z_1\dots\forall z_n\left[\bigwedge_{i=1}^n G(z_i)\to \left(\psi(y,\overline{z})\leftrightarrow\psi(y',\overline{z})\right)\right],$$ and consider the family of formulas $$r(y,y')=\left\{d_px\varphi(x,y),\neg d_px\varphi(x,y')\right\}\cup\left\{\widehat{\psi}(y,y'):\psi(y,\overline{z})\in\text{Form}\right\},$$ where $\text{Form}$ is the set of formulas without parameters. We claim that $r$ is finitely satisfiable in $M$. To see this, note that by taking conjunctions we may replace the set on the right with a single formula $\widehat{\psi}(y,y')$ for some $\psi(y,\overline{z})\in\text{Form}$. Now, we know that $\operatorname{tp}(n/G(N))=\operatorname{tp}(n'/G(N))$, so we have $N\models \widehat\psi(n,n')$. In particular, the formula $\varphi(x,n)\wedge\neg\varphi(x,n')\wedge\widehat\psi(n,n')$ lies in $q$. But $q$ is an heir of $p$, so there are $m,m'\in M$ such that the same formula but with $n,n'$ replaced by $m,m'$ lies in $p$. In particular, we have $\varphi(x,m)\in p$ and $\varphi(x,m')\notin p$, so $$M\models d_px\varphi(x,m)\wedge \neg d_px\varphi(x,m'),$$ and $M\models\widehat\psi(m,m')$. Thus $m$ and $m'$ give the desired witnesses, and hence $r(y,y')$ is consistent.

Now, $r(y,y')$ contains only finitely many parameters, all of which lie in $M$, so by $\aleph_0$-saturation of $M$ there exist $m,m'\in M$ with $M\models r(m,m')$. By construction, we have $M\models\widehat{\psi}(m,m')$ for every formula $\psi(y,\overline{z})$, whence $\operatorname{tp}(m/G(M))=\operatorname{tp}(m'/G(M))$. But also $$M\models d_px\varphi(x,m)\wedge \neg d_px\varphi(x,m'),$$ so $\varphi(x,m)\wedge\neg\varphi(x,m')\in p$, and hence $p$ is not $G(M)$-invariant, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it change the situation if $G$ is not only a definable set but a definable group?

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández I highly doubt the situation changes if  is not a definable type. as for whether you can make do without an $\aleph_0$-saturation hypothesis on $M$ if $G$ is a definable group, I do not know off the top of my head; perhaps it's worth asking as a separate question :)

Comment: Aha - your suggestion that $G$ might be a definable group clears everything up. If we understand the meaning of "$G(M)$-invariance" correctly, everything is easy (see my answer). This demonstrates the importance of being clear on the definitions and making sure you include all the relevant definitions in your question!

Answer (score 2):

Your comment to Atticus's answer suggests a different interpretation, under which the question has an easy positive answer.

Let $G$ be a definable *group* in a theory $T$. For any model $M\models T$, let $S_G(M)$ be the space of types over $M$ which contain the formula defining $G$. Then there is a natural action of $G(M)$ on $S_G(M)$ by translation: for $g\in G(M)$ and a type $p\in S_G(M)$, define $g\cdot p = \text{tp}((g\cdot a) / M)$ for any realization $a$ of $p$ in an elementary extension $M\preceq N$ (here $(g\cdot a)$ refers to the product of $g$ and $a$ in the group $G(N)$). More concretely, $g\cdot p = \{\varphi(x,m)\mid \varphi(g\cdot x,m)\in p\}$.

Now let $M\preceq N$ be models of $T$, and let $p\in S_G(M)$ be $G(M)$-invariant, meaning that it is fixed by the action of $G(M)$ on $S_G(M)$ defined above. Let $q\in S_G(N)$ be an heir of $p$. Then the claim is that $q$ is $G(N)$-invariant.

Suppose $q$ is not $G(N)$-invariant. Then there is some $g\in G(N)$ and some formula $\varphi(x,n)$ with $n\in N$ such that $\varphi(x,n)\in q$ but $\varphi(g\cdot x,n)\notin q$. Then the conjunction $G(g)\land \varphi(x,n)\land \lnot \varphi(g\cdot x,n)$ is in $q$, and since $q$ is an heir of $p$, there are some $h,m\in M$ such that $G(h)\land \varphi(x,m)\land \lnot \varphi(h\cdot x,m)$ is in $p$. But this contradicts $G(M)$-invariance of $p$.

Comment: oh!! lol that makes considerably more sense

Comment: I do find it amusing that between the three of us we managed to formulate a true but utterly incorrect interpretation of the question. I *was* wondering about the $S_G(M)$ notation... I figured it was just a shorthand for the set of $G(M)$-invariant types over $M$.

Comment: Yes, this makes much more sense, somehow I mixed the definitions of invariance. I accepted the other answer because it answer the question as is posted.